# Runge Kutta fourth order

Tags: warning-messages, differential-equations

I´m trying to run a fourth order Runge Kutta in Mathematica but the thing is that I´m so so new in Mathematica that I am not even sure what I´m doing. I have these two coupled equations:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = z$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx} = 6y - z$$

with these initial conditions:
$$y(0) = 3$$
$$z(0) = 1$$

So, I was looking for the code and I found this one and I tried to modify it for this problem:

```
yinit=List[0, 3, 1]
y=List[x, y, z]
func=List[y'[x]/dx = z, z'[x]/dx = 6 y - z]
step = 0.1
t = 1
RungeKutta[func_List, yinit_List, y_List, step_] :=
   
 Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4},
  k1 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, yinit}]];
  k2 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k1/2 + yinit}]];
  k3 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k2/2 + yinit}]];
  k4 = step N[func /. MapThread[Rule, {y, k3 + yinit}]];
  yinit + Total[{k1, 2 k2, 2 k3, k4}]/6]

NestList[RungeKutta[func, #, y, step] &, N[yinit], Round[t/step]]
```

but I get the next errors:

> "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {x,y,z}."
>
> Tag Hold in Hold $\frac{[y'[x]]}{dx}$ is protected
>
> "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {x,y,z}"
> Further output of RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be suppressed during this calculation

Maybe I am doing many wrong thing but this noob would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Would either of these and examples therein help? [ExplicitRungeKutta](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html) and [ImplicitRungeKutta] (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveImplicitRungeKutta.html)

Comment: It seems you are confused about very basic syntax here. At least I do not understand, what `yinit_List[0, 3, 1]` is supposed to do. Maybe it should be `yinit=List[0, 3, 1]`. You can edit and correct your question.

Comment: Sorry @Johu, is supposed that yinit are the initial conditions, func is the list of the functions and y are the variables.

Comment: Also, I suspect `List[y'[x]/dx = z, z'[x]/dx = 6 y - z]` does not make any sense. You might want to look up [the difference between `=` and `==`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/115443#115443)

Comment: If you just want to solve the differential equations numerically rather than implement your own Runge-Kutta, try `NDSolve`.

Comment: Why apply a numerical method here? After all, the equations form a homogeneous linear system, which *Mathematica* can solve symbolically: `DSolve[{y'[x] == z[x], z'[x] == 6 y[x] - z[x], y[0] == 3, 
  z[0] == 1}, {y[x], z[x]}, x]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system = {y'[x] == z[x], z'[x] == 6 y[x] - z[x], y[0] == 3, z[0] == 1}
mma = NDSolve[system, {y[x], z[x]}, {x, 0, 0.5},
   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", "StartingStepSize" -> 1/5]
Plot[{y[x] /. mma, z[x] /. mma}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Diogo! Just one more thing, how can I instead of plotting the data, show the calculations in a table? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Rung-Kutta works, but I can point to at least two errors in your code:

1. In the second line of the code `y=List[x, y, z]` you use the variable `y` in its own definition, and this is what creates the recursion error.
2. In the third line `func=List[y'[x]/dx = z, z'[x]/dx = 6 y - z]`, what are `y'[x]/dx` and `z'[x]/dx` exactly? To denote the derivatives you either type `y'[x]` and `z'[x]`, or type `D[y[x],x]` and `D[z[x],x]`. And if  `func`is a list of equations (and not definitions), then you need to use the double equal sign `==` instead of a single equal `=`.